# Upgrading Stash from 2.3.6 to 2.5.9 breaks a template

Tags: stash

I am running ExpressionEngine 2.7.2 with Stash 2.3.6.  I tried updating Stash to 2.5.9 but found one of my templates using Stash now does not obtain the stashed variables.  Here is the salient portion of my template:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name='mystash' parse_tags='yes' parse_depth='1'}
{exp:channel:entries channel="group_photo_tags" entry_id="2078"}
{group_photo_entry}
{stash:my_height}{exp:math formula='([1] * [3]) / [2]' params='{img-width}|{group_photo_entry:file_name}{width}{/group_photo_entry:file_name}|{group_photo_entry:file_name}{height}{/group_photo_entry:file_name}' round='up'}{/stash:my_height}
{stash:my_scale}{exp:math formula='[1] / [2]' params='{img-width}|{group_photo_entry:file_name}{width}{/group_photo_entry:file_name}' decimals='4'}{/stash:my_scale}
{stash:my_file}{group_photo_entry:file_name}{/stash:my_file}
{/group_photo_entry}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name='mystash' parse_tags='yes' parse_conditionals='yes' parse_depth='1'}
{exp:channel:entries channel="group_photo_tags" entry_id="2078"}

<h3>{title} - {group_photo_entry}{group_photo_entry:title}{/group_photo_entry}</h3>
  {group_photo_entry}

<!--[if lt IE 9]> <p>Note: for older browsers, the person's face will not be circled</p><div id="mydiv" style="width: {img-width}px; height:{my_height}px;"><img src="{my_file}" width="{img-width}" height="{my_height}" /> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <div id="mydiv" style="width: {img-width}px; height:{my_height}px;"> <!--<![endif]-->
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="{img-width}" height="{my_height}">
</canvas>

{/group_photo_entry}

<script type="text/javascript">

var c=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
drawphoto(c, ctx, drawcircle);

function drawphoto(c, ctx, onload){
var photo = new Image();
   photo.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(photo,0,0,{img-width},{my_height});
      onload(c,ctx);
   };
photo.src = "{my_file}";
}

function drawcircle(c,ctx){
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(
{exp:math formula='[1] * [2]' params='{my_scale}|{x}'},
{exp:math formula='[1] * [2]' params='{my_scale}|{y}'},
{exp:math formula='[1] * [2]' params='{my_scale}|{radius}'}*2
,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineWidth = 4;
ctx.stroke();
}
</script>
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

A view of the page source after the update shows that the stash variables are now parsed as blank, leaving the formulas to calculate 0 and so rendering no image.  I suspect a parse order issue, but do not see where this is occurring.

Comment: Might be something - try a greater depth in your stash set and remove it from your stash get.

Comment: & why are you using exp tags imside your staah get?

Comment: The changes to the depth fixed this!  Thanks!  (As to why the exp tags are inside the get_list, this is the first way I got this to work.  And I live by the 'if it ain't broke, don't fix it' mantra!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy it was a simple fix. For future reference, if a comment leads you to the solution, you should give the commentator an opportunity to post it as an 'answer'. The whole SE system is built on points and points are used to boost your credibility.

Whilst the comment was correct I'd likely go a step further as stash is of no use in your scenario as your stash a list then getting the list whilst also using exp:channel tags again.

```
//Rather then using set_list to capture 1 entry, use it to capture 100 (or all)
{exp:stash:set_list name='mystash' parse_tags='yes' parse_depth='2'}
{exp:channel:entries channel="group_photo_tags" limit="100"} //capture 100 entries
  {stash:entry_name}{title}{/stash:entry_name}//Record title of entry
  {stash:entry_url}{url_title}{/stash:entry_url}//Record the URL of the entry for matching
  //Use a nested list for recording the gallery matrix/grid
  {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="{entry_url}_gallery" parse_tags="yes"}
  {group_photo_entry}
        {stash:my_title}{title}{/stash:my_title}// Grab the title of the image
        {stash:my_width}{img-width}{/stash:my_width}
        {stash:my_height}{exp:math formula='([1] * [3]) / [2]' params='{img-width}| {group_photo_entry:file_name}{width}{/group_photo_entry:file_name}|{group_photo_entry:file_name}{height}{/group_photo_entry:file_name}' round='up'}  
        {/stash:my_height}
        {stash:my_scale}{exp:math formula='[1] / [2]' params='{img-width}|{group_photo_entry:file_name}{width}{/group_photo_entry:file_name}' decimals='4'
        {/stash:my_scale}
        {stash:my_file}{group_photo_entry:file_name}{/stash:my_file}
  {/group_photo_entry}
  {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

//Now we can use get list to spit out one particular entry using the match + against
variables. I'm assuming there will be a segment in the URL (say it's segment_3)
we can use to match a conditional against.
{exp:stash:get_list
   name='mystash'
   parse_tags='yes'
   parse_conditionals='yes'
   match="#^{segment_3}$#" against="entry_url"}

<h3>{entry_title} - {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="{entry_url}_gallery"} {my_title}</h3>

<!--[if lt IE 9]> <p>Note: for older browsers, the person's face will not be circled</p><div id="mydiv" style="width: {my_width}px; height:{my_height}px;"><img src="{my_file}" width="{my_width}" height="{my_height}" /> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <div id="mydiv" style="width: {my_width}px; height:{my_height}px;"> <!--<![endif]-->
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="{my_width}" height="{my_height}">
</canvas>


<script type="text/javascript">

var c=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
drawphoto(c, ctx, drawcircle);

function drawphoto(c, ctx, onload){
var photo = new Image();
   photo.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(photo,0,0,{my_width},{my_height});
      onload(c,ctx);
   };
photo.src = "{my_file}";
}

function drawcircle(c,ctx){
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(
{exp:math formula='[1] * [2]' params='{my_scale}|{x}'},
{exp:math formula='[1] * [2]' params='{my_scale}|{y}'},
{exp:math formula='[1] * [2]' params='{my_scale}|{radius}'}*2
,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineWidth = 4;
ctx.stroke();
}
</script>
</div>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

So basically we use the stash_set_list to capture **all** fields from a set number of entries. We use the `:nested` tag to create a related list from either a matrix or grid field within the parent entry.

With all that info now recorded, we can use stash_get and stash_get:nested along with `match=' and`against=` to only return the valid stashed content from the list.

The code above is not guaranteed to work, I've simply refactored your code to illustrate how it should work. Once you've got it working, you can then start caching the results as stash can be saved to the DB in one blob saving a ton of queries, but thats for another time.

Comment: Well, this template always only shows a single entry (I chose the example one, but later it uses one which is chosen by the user).  The trick was that, early on in my use of Stash as a beginner, I had trouble getting stash:set and stash:get to work.  I played with this a bit now and removed the set_list part entirely (and the get_list) and began the channel entries part with a sequence of stash:set lines to set the three variables I needed to reuse later in the template.  This worked fine and is a much better coding.

Answer (score 0):

Stuartmcd69 got it right with the change in depth.  Apparently, the update to Stash has parsing changes which caused this.  When I changed the set_list depth to '2' and removed the depth from get_list, the template worked properly under the new version of Stash.